# How to do validation on a class that inherit a model?

Tags: validation, inheritance, model-view-controller, model

How do I implement validation on a class that inherit a model?

I using the using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to do the validation.
I have a class that inherit the Movie model:

```
public class AMovie : Movie
```

I tried to set the validation on the Movie model.
And I have a view that inherit AMovie class, but it does not take the effect.

On the view I set set the validation message like this:

```
<td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MovieName, new { PlaceHolder = "Movie Name" })%></td>
<td><%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MovieName)%></td>
```

**EDIT[Solution]**

I found out a solution that just use the 'New' keyword to override the model class. Example:

Model class has:

```
public string movieName {get;set;}
```

Then child class key in:

```
public new string movieName{get;set;}
```

Then put the validation on top of it. like this:

```
[Required]
public new string movieName{get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution that just use the 'New' keyword to override the model class. Example:

Model class has:

```
public string movieName {get;set;}
```

Then child class key in:

```
public new string movieName{get;set;}
```

Then put the validation on top of it. like this:

```
[Required]
public new string movieName{get;set;}
```